# Is std::vector trivially copyable and why?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, std

I came across with an issue with `std::vector<T>`, where `T` is a built-in type saying that the vector is not trivially copyable.

I was wondering if it's right and am looking for the reason.

Comment: You could always check with [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `vector` grows as data is added to it. This means that one does not need to know upfront how much space is needed to store all its data. The `vector` solves this problem by allocating (and reallocating) a separate storage buffer on the heap. This buffer is managed internally while providing an interface that can be though of as a variably sized array.

Now if an object is trivially-constructable, one should be able to copy/clone the object simply using `memcpy(dest, &a, sizeof(a))`. If one were to do this for a `vector`, one would have 2 vector objects pointing to the same storage buffer. This will result in horrible undefined behaviour. Copying a vector therefore requires that one duplicate the internal storage, duplicate its parameters and then set the internal pointer to point to the correct storage buffer. This requires internal knowledge of the object to do.

`std::array` however, has a static size set at compile time. It does not have internal pointers and can therefore be copied simply by using `memcpy`. It therefore is trivial to copy.

Answer (score 9):

Formally, a `std::vector<T>` (for any `T`) is not [trivially copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) because its copy constructor is not [trivial](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Trivial_copy_constructor), if only because it's user-provided (as opposed to implicitly-defined).

Practically speaking, copying a vector involves more than making a shallow copy of its data members - it requires allocating a memory buffer on the heap and copying over its contents from another vector's heap-allocated buffer.

Comment: Its move constructor, copy and move assignment, and destructor are all non-trivial as well.